# ANDROID: How to make the app record all the ERROR logs in a database?

Tags: java, android, database, logging, error-handling

I'm going to make a beta from my app and I'd like to record all the Exceptions (Log ERRORS) in a database. There's a way to catch all the exceptions and record it in a way that i could find more bugs and fix them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the easiest way is to have a method responsible for saving the data into database.

Then you should wrap your codes in `try...catch` block and catch all possible exceptions and pass the exception message to that method.

Comment: Theres no a way that's automatic... because i don't know where it will gives me an exception... I run the risk to don't catch some possible exceptions... that the users could face...

Comment: its either you catch exceptions and log them so that you know it happened, or let it happen and go through Log files stored in the system and find the ones related to you each time you want to collect them